# Unable to install node ZeroMQ through npm in windows

Tags: node.js, npm, queue, zeromq

We are trying to install  zeromq through npm on windows8 64 bit 
*we install visual studio 2010 and python
but still we are getting the error as follows:

```
D:\Projects\changi\node_modules\zmq>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-g
yp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Python27 ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:849:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at doNTCallback2 (node.js:430:9)
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:344:17)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\changi\node_modules\zmq
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "zmq"
npm ERR! node v4.1.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! zmq@2.14.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.14.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the zmq package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zmq
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Projects\changi\npm-debug.log
```

Could you please tell us what we are missing or point us to some document which will help us to do this thanks for ur time

Comment: Have you installed zeromq?

Comment: it is installed according to this documentation http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows

Answer (score 0):

Set PYTHON Enviorment Variable.

Comment: after setting the python environmental variable i am getting the error has in the edited post please check

Comment: Check installation guide here : https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp   and check you have all things in place or not

Answer (score 0):

```
* Install python. Make sure Python 2.7.x with the steps provided below
    http://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/
    And confirm by running below commands: 
    $ python -V
    Python 2.7.9
*installed node-gyp manually:
        $ npm install -g node-gyp
*installed 'Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop'
*install 'Windows7 SDK' 
  *And do  npm install zmq
and it worked!
```